# "Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger" with custom maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have written a small custom maven plugin, and it runs fine.. most of the time.

When using it, it's configured to run on test phase, and I see it executing, no problem. Now problem comes later, when I do *mvn clean install* or *mvn clean deploy* in the project using the plugin : it fails with a message I can't make sense of. And it clearly comes from my plugin, because if I remove it, then *mvn clean install* works.

Error message is very long and it has 4 similar traces as the one below.

I am quite clueless with where it can come from.. any idea ?

```
 Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.logger
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver
[ERROR] while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionResolver
[ERROR] for parameter 2 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver
[ERROR] while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.ArtifactResolver
[ERROR] for parameter 2 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader
[ERROR] while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.ArtifactDescriptorReader
[ERROR] for parameter 1 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector
[ERROR] while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.DependencyCollector
[ERROR] for parameter 5 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
[ERROR] while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.ArtifactInstaller
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.Wir
eModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.log
ger to org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFactory
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertyField.set(BeanPropertyField.java:72)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders$7.get(BeanProviders.java:160)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
[ERROR] at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:543)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 4 errors
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install
```

Comment: Had almost the same exception while compiling https://github.com/javaee/metro-wsit. The issue occurred in 3.3.9. Resolved it by using Maven 3.6

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After some research, I felt it looked like some version incompatibility. and indeed, it is, between the maven version I am using to build the applications using the plugin, and the maven core version used in the plugin.

- in my plugin, I was using latest maven core version available as a dependency, ie 3.5.2
- I am building the plugin with Maven 3.3.1 and build is OK.
- but when I build a project using the plugin, with Maven 3.3.1, the problem happens.

I downgraded maven core to 3.3.9, then rebuilt my plugin, and it works now.

I guess there are some incompatibilities between maven core 3.5.x and previous maven runtime..

I see on https://jaxenter.com/apache-maven-3-5-0-nothing-see-3-4-0-move-along-133180.html that they switched *... from Eclipse Aether to Maven Artifact Resolver*

but what was very confusing is that my build was failing not at the time of my plugin being called, but after.

Comment: thank you for your solution. Just had the problem with the spotbugs maven plugin. After upgrading the Maven version used by Eclipse the problem was gone.

Comment: Just had the same issue with the spotbugs maven plugin. Upgrading to the latest maven version solved the problem for me as well.

Comment: aether related dependencies in maven-core-3.3.1 is no longer a dependency in maven-core-3.5.2. see: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.1/maven-core/pom.xml and https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.5.2/maven-core/pom.xml

Comment: It would better if you add step to update the apache-maven version in elipse/STS/any IDE you use.

Answer (score 6):

if you are running inside IntelliJ IDEA go to

> - Build -> Execution, Deployment > Build tools > Maven
> - Update maven directory as your maven /dir. (maven-3.6.0)
>
> The default one is 3.3.9 for IntelliJ idea 2018.3.1

[image]

Comment: If trying to build through IntelliJ terminal, and you have  M2_HOME system variable set, it is not enough to just change the options in settings. I had to download an updated maven version, and update my M2_HOME, and restart IntelliJ. Check with mvn -version, to see the current version, and if your settings updates has gone through.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue but after updating maven version from 3.3.9 to 3.6.3 solved my problem. Please try upgrading maven to 3.6.X . Hope this helps someone. Happy Learning :).

Comment: In my case I resolved this issue with upgraded my maven install to 3.6.3

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! I was using maven-processor-plugin 5.0-rc2 with Maven 3.3.9, upgraded to Maven 3.6.3 and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

For a spring boot project, if you can't easily update maven version for some reason ( in my case the error appeared in automated builds which used a maven docker container from a custom docker registry )

Specifying a version for plugin **spring-boot-maven-plugin** fixed the issue for me

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a version for plugin spring-boot-maven-plugin fixed the issue for me as well. Here is what I changed:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and changed jdeb plugin version and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had met the same issue when upgrade jdeb from 1.5 to 1.7.  And downgrade it to 1.5 and it fixed.

```
                        <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 3.3.9 maven was mandatory to use as other project were  using same maven in jenkins build.

So I downgraded my com.spotify plugin from 1.4.10 to 1.4.6 by refering to below link

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin/1.4.6
```

in this link we can see maven supported version

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the other answer which recommends downgrading spotify, in my case updating spotify version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the version of maven on your command prompt with "mvn --version".
2. run the "mvn deploy" on command line to see if that works.
3. Go to Build -> Execution, Deployment > Build tools > Maven in IntelliJ and change the version of maven to the version available on your pc instead of the default bundle provided.

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade the dockerfile-maven-plugin version 1.4.10 to 1.4.1

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</plugin>
```