# JENKINS : Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider.logger

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When running my job im getting this error:

```
Parsing POMs
12:04:09 ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
12:04:09 hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
12:04:09 
12:04:09 1) Error injecting: private org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider.logger
12:04:09   while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.LocalRepositoryProvider
12:04:09     for parameter 8 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:121)
12:04:09   while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   while locating org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem
12:04:09   while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
12:04:09   while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
12:04:09   while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   at ClassRealm[maven, parent: ClassRealm[maven-parent, parent: null]] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
12:04:09   while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
12:04:09 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger field org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider.logger to org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.PlexusLoggerFactory
12:04:09    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
12:04:09    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
12:04:09    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
12:04:09    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
12:04:09    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanPropertyField.set(BeanPropertyField.java:74)
12:04:09    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
12:04:09    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
12:04:09    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
```

**Same job is running perfectly under another jenkins**

Using already same version of maven this solution wont help : [Can not set org.eclipse.aether.spi.log.Logger” with custom maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920305/can-not-set-org-eclipse-aether-spi-log-logger-with-custom-maven-plugin)

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you have many versions of plugins/jar containing the class `org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider.logger`. If yes, delete one to fix the conflict.

Available for more help.

Comment: I found two versions of  aether-impl.jar in my maven-plugin directory.. problem resolved once i removed one..

Comment: i am having the same issue while running build from jenkins

Comment: i am having the same issue while running build from jenkins but i have checked  i have only one version of this jar?